# What package should i install to get Win32 console application (Visual Stdio 2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

[My installed or something in my vs 2019 files screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDIh3.png)

[My installed or something in my vs 2019 files widen screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3kpH.png)

i dont have templates or any win32 console application
pls help me im new to vs 2019
i only coded two applications ( Windows Form Application )

Comment: Note that VS comes with the *VS Developers Command Prompt". It is a command (or now Powershell) with the development environment defined for it. When compiling small programs (or even large complex programs), you can simply open the developer command prompt and compile your code from the command line without ever having to mess with setting up a project. `cl.exe` is the VS compiler. Check `cl /?` for a list of all options.

Comment: You probably just need to go to New project rather than new file

Answer (score 1):

To install other templates, you can open the Visual Studio Installer (open by searching in the windows menu). Choose your VS installation, click more then modify. [image]

Ensure the above option is ticked, then click modify at the bottom.

When you open VS, this is the project type you should make.
[image]

Comment: That's the ticket. Good ole Desktop Development C++.

Answer (score 0):

[.Net Desktop Development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K91IM.png)

This would help you developing console apps on vs 2019
You could get to vs installer from "Tools>get tools and features"